# Get a datasource from a config file

Tags: spring-boot, datasource

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm writing a database HealthIndicator. I meet difficulties to get as a Java object the datasource described in my application.yml :

```
datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://10.26.80.192/myDB
    username: postgres
    password:
```

The Java code I tried is :

```
@Component
public class DBHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Bean(name="getDataSource")  
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource")  
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {  
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();  
    }  

     public DBHealthIndicator() {
        super();
    }

    private boolean result = false;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSourceHealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator() {
         return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(getDataSource(), "SELECT * FROM USERS");
    }

   @Override
   protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {

        Health h = dbHealthIndicator().health();
        Status status = h.getStatus();
        if (status != null && "DOWN".equals(status.getCode())) {
             result = false;
        } else {
             result = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(boolean result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

The error I get is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:649)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
.....
```

Comment: `jdbcUrl` should be `url`, no?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not write this configuration file. A colleague of mine did and the conf file have not caused any error so far

Comment: Have you tried to change it? The error indicates that there's no url for your datasource - the error doesn't look like beeing related to the rest of your code

Comment: `jdbcUrl` is a property that is specific to Hikari. Others here gave you the right information. I fail to see why you're writing all that code when Spring Boot does that for you...

Comment: I decided to use a DataSourceHealthIndicator, which is provided by Spring Boot. Thank you all for your help and your explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it will initialize the `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` which extends from `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy`, if you dive into this class, it has the 'setUrl(String url)', so you need config the properties with

```
datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://10.26.80.192/myDB
    username: postgres
    password:
```